# Android Permissions Error

Tags: android, android-permissions

Whats wrong with my manifest file? my app crashes saying no permissions to send sms even added  in my manifest file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.righteous_05.examapp">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>


        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".AdminActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".ConductExam" />
            <activity android:name=".ResultActivity"></activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Are you running this on Android 6?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/cant-get-the-permission

Answer (score 0):

Your Android Manifest is fine for getting permissions. However, if you are trying this on Android 6.0, the app will fail because the Permission System in Android Marshmallow is different. `SEND_SMS` is classified as "Dangerous" permission, so you need to use `checkSelfPermission()` and `requestPermissions()` in Marshmallow. Like this -

```
//This code will fail on devices below Android 6.0, so the below if statement is neccessary
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ContextCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS});
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement this code but it says  cannot find symbol method requestPermissions(this,String[])